# Angular2 Typescript declare variable any throws ReferenceError

Tags: angular, typescript, declare, any, referenceerror

Hi StackOverflow community,

I have JavaScript code outside which set global js variable, but in some cases this variable does not exist. I have configuration class in Angular2 which import that global variable via declare var any. In the class I have static variable with ternary operator which checks if this global variable exists (!=null) then set some statement but it throws: Uncaught ReferenceError: IMPORTED_VAR is not defined. How to solve it?

```
declare var IMPORTED_VAR:any;
export class ConfigurationClass {
  public static CONF_VAR = IMPORTED_VAR ? IMPORTED_VAR : "SOMETHING";
}
```

Comment: you don't need to use declare. just use var IMPORTED_VAR:any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created static constructor in typescript with handling this exception

Comment: How? Can you please share code?

Answer (score -2):

```
declare var IMPORTED_VAR:any;
export class ConfigurationClass {
  public static CONF_VAR = (IMPORTED_VAR.hasOwnProperty("length") && IMPORTED_VAR.length>0) ? IMPORTED_VAR : "SOMETHING";
}
```

Comment: when you use `declare` then it will only declaration not real value of instance so in above code we can check if instance has properties. Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately it still throws ReferenceError if the imported variable does not exist.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.